# Magento Observer Inject Data Into Block

Tags: magento

I have:

1. Created an event observer for core_block_abstract_to_html_after
2. Waited for class "Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Totals" in an if statement
3. got the block via the observer and called addTotal();

This is where I am stuck... If I dump the block I can see my newly added total HOWEVER its not showing in the HTML. Surely there has to be a way to "refresh" the HTML or something so that it will include the newly added data. Here is the code I have thus far...

```
<?php
class Company_Extension_Model_Totals {

    public function blockToHtmlAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
        $block = $observer->getBlock();
        $class = get_class($block);

        if($class == 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Totals'){
            $transport = $observer->getTransport();

            $block->addTotal(new Varien_Object(array(
                'code'      => 'newmethod',
                'value'     => '10',
                'base_value'=> '10',
                'label'     => 'New Method',
                'area'      => 'footer'
            )), 'last');

            #$transport->setHtml($output);
        }

    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
public function handleBlockOutput($observer)
{
    /* @var $block Mage_Core_Block_Abstract */
    $block = $observer->getBlock();

    if ($block instanceof Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List) {
        $transport = $observer->getTransport();
        $html = $transport->getHtml();

        if (strpos($html, "amasty-layered-navigation") === FALSE){
            $html = some_custom_logic();

            $transport->setHtml($html);
        }
    }
}
```

So the observer allows to modify the HTML, not the block. You can get the block HTML and add a string to it.  Will it work for you?

Also you can use layout to call block functions:

```
            <block type ="amfinder/form" name="amasty-products-finder">
                <action method="setId"><id>1</id></action>    <!--  with params -->   
                <action method="apply" />   <!--  without params --> 
            </block>
```

Comment: I would much rather modify the block before it gets rendered... do any of the observers allow of this? Or is there a way to set the html to nothing and then re-render it?

Comment: I assume you do not want to rewrite blocks.  But what if you call the addTotal in the layout?

Comment: I'd like to keep the amounts of files I have to manage and override to a minimum. From what I can tell though, about the only way I can keep from having to create new blocks and layouts is to over ride Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Totals and just directly apply my custom totals to $this->_totals in the _initTotals() function